# vba input formula referencing cell from another dynamic sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to input formula into cells based on the month of the year. 
The problem I am facing now is that the same string that is used to name the sheet is not able to be populated nicely into the formula.
what I am getting is `=Jan-'19'!N876` instead of `='Jan-19'!N876` in the cell.
Appreciate if anyone could help with that.
Thanks!

```
Sub Summary()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim row As String
Dim newmth As String
newmth = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmm-yy")

row = 4
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets(newmth)
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Summary")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While sht2.Range("B" & (row)) <> ""

If sht2.Range("B" & (row)).Text = newmth Then

sht2.Range("D" & (row)).Formula = "=" & sht1.Name & "!" & "N876"

End If
row = row + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sht2.Range("D" & (row)).Formula = "= '" & sht1.Name & "'!" & "N876"`